# How to let the background full this #68A4C4 color and is under another picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to let the background full this #68A4C4 color  and  is under another picture ?
I want to like  this picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0srMq.jpg), but I only can do like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jssVM.png)
I am a newbie in html and css, I try so many times, but didn't work.

this is my css code and html code    thank you!

```css
/**
* Template Name: Moderna - v2.1.0
* Template URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/free-bootstrap-template-corporate-moderna/
* Author: BootstrapMade.com
* License: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# General
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}

a {
  color: #4fa6d5;
}

a:hover {
  color: #45beff;
  text-decoration: none;
}



/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Back to top button
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  background: #68A4C4;
  color: #fff;
  transition: display 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.back-to-top i {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
}

.back-to-top:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #85b6cf;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
  height: 80px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: #1e4356;
}

#header.header-transparent {
  background: none;
}

#header.header-scrolled {
  background: rgba(30, 67, 86, 0.8);
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}


/*會跟著滾動的微學分整合資訊系統，但是手機板無法 會跑版 待解決。*/
#header .logo span {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 300px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 8px;   /*字母间距*/
  
  
}

#header .logo h1 a, #header .logo h1 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header .logo img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 40px;
}

#main {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Navigation Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Desktop Navigation */
.nav-menu, .nav-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
}

.nav-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.nav-menu a:hover, .nav-menu .active > a, .nav-menu li:hover > a {
  color: #a2cce3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu .drop-down ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% - 30px);
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
  transition: ease all 0.3s;
}

.nav-menu .drop-down:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

.nav-menu .drop-down li {
  min-width: 180px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-menu .drop-down ul a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #1c3745;
}

.nav-menu .drop-down ul a:hover, .nav-menu .drop-down ul .active > a, .nav-menu .drop-down ul li:hover > a {
  color: #68A4C4;
}

.nav-menu .drop-down > a:after {
  content: "\ea99";
  font-family: IcoFont;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.nav-menu .drop-down .drop-down ul {
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.nav-menu .drop-down .drop-down:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.nav-menu .drop-down .drop-down > a {
  padding-right: 35px;
}

.nav-menu .drop-down .drop-down > a:after {
  content: "\eaa0";
  font-family: IcoFont;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 1366px) {
  .nav-menu .drop-down .drop-down ul {
    left: -90%;
  }
  .nav-menu .drop-down .drop-down:hover > ul {
    left: -100%;
  }
  .nav-menu .drop-down .drop-down > a:after {
    content: "\ea9d";
  }
}

/* Mobile Navigation */
.mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow-y: auto;
  left: -260px;
  width: 260px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  background: #1e4356;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.mobile-nav * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.mobile-nav a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #ddecf5;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.mobile-nav a:hover, .mobile-nav .active > a, .mobile-nav li:hover > a {
  color: #a2cce3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mobile-nav .drop-down > a:after {
  content: "\ea99";
  font-family: IcoFont;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

.mobile-nav .active.drop-down > a:after {
  content: "\eaa0";
}

.mobile-nav .drop-down > a {
  padding-right: 35px;
}

.mobile-nav .drop-down ul {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-nav .drop-down li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 9998;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  outline: none !important;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: right;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #fff;
}

.mobile-nav-overly {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9997;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(30, 67, 86, 0.9);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-nav-active .mobile-nav {
  left: 0;
}

.mobile-nav-active .mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #fff;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Hero Section
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#hero::after {
 background:  #68A4C4;
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
  color:  #68A4C4;
  font-size: 14px;
}


/*
#hero::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 130%;
  height: 96%;
  background: url("../img/tree.jpg" );
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(18px) rotate(2deg);
}
*/
 
#hero .carousel-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.test{
    
    padding: 0 0 0 100px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

.input-group{
    padding: 0 0 0 500px;
}


#hero h2 {
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#hero p {
  width: 80%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
  margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.picture{
    margin-top: -300px;
    float:right;
}

.picture2{
    padding: 0 50 0 500px;
    
}



@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #hero p {
    width: 60%;
  }
  #hero .carousel-control-prev, #hero .carousel-control-next {
    width: 5%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #hero::after {
    width: 180%;
    height: 95%;
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  #hero::before {
    top: 0;
    width: 180%;
    height: 94%;
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(20px) rotate(4deg);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  #hero h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  #hero::after {
    left: 40%;
    top: 0;
    width: 200%;
    height: 95%;
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  #hero::before {
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    width: 200%;
    height: 94%;
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(20px) rotate(4deg);
  }
}




/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Footer
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#footer {
  background: #0b212d;
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
}


#footer .copyright {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-tw">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>微學分整合資訊系統</title>

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- =======================================================
  * Template Name: Moderna - v2.1.0
  * Template URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/free-bootstrap-template-corporate-moderna/
  * Author: BootstrapMade.com
  * License: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
  ======================================================== -->
</head>

<body>

  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="fixed-top header-transparent">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="logo float-left">
        <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
         <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"><span style="color:white;" >微學分整合資訊系統</span></a>
      </div>

        

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->

  <!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
  <section id="hero" class="d-flex justify-cntent-center align-items-center">
    <div id="heroCarousel" class="container carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Slide 1 -->
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="carousel-container">
          
         
          
          
            <div class="container">
            <div class="test">
         <img src="assets/img/graduated.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>  
        </div>  
          
        
            
        <div class="container">
        <form>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" style=width:200px>
        </div> 
    <br>
    
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" style=width:200px>
        </div>
        
        </form>
        </div>    
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </section><!-- End Hero -->
  


  
          <!--picture-->
      <div class="picture">
          <div class="col-md-3">
          <div align="right">
            <img src="assets/img/tree.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      
    <div class="picture">  
<img src="assets/img/cloud.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
 </div>




  
  <a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="icofont-simple-up"></i></a>

  <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
  <script src="assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/counterup/counterup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Template Main JS File -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the CSS? why not simply add the color as background-color of them body. You can also use multiple background images and use gradients to add a background-color along with a background image

Comment: Have you tried setting background-color on the body element?

Comment: Thank your suggest.  I success  when I trid setting background-color on the body element